# Loopback filter NOT BETWEEN date

Tags: mysql, node.js, orm, loopbackjs

I'm using loopback models to filter a list of events with start and end dates and I want to return a list of events that are NOT between two specific dates. I thought something like this should work:

```
const eventList = await Events.find({ 
  where: {
    startDate: {
      not: {
        between: [unavailableStarting, unavailableEnding],
      },
    },
    endDate: {
      not: {
        between: [unavailableStarting, unavailableEnding],
      },
    },
  },
});
```

If you take out the `not` part, this works fine for getting all events that ARE between the dates. How do I make a `NOT BETWEEN` filter work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell there is no way to use NOT BETWEEN with loopback models, but I did make it work with lt gt:

```
const eventList = await Events.find({
  where: {
    and:[{
      or: [
        { startDate: { lt: unavailableStarting } },
        { startDate: { gt: unavailableEnding } },
      ]
    },
    {
      or: [
        { endDate: { gt: unavailableStarting } },
        { endDate: { lt: unavailableEnding } },
      ]
    }
  ]},
});
```

Comment: what is unavailableString?

Comment: @NadeemYousaf it means replace it with you value, its just a placeholder :P